# obtaining a goodness of fit indices for an analysis with tweedie distribution

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, glmmtmb, tweedie-distribution

I performed an analysis specifying a dependent variable with a tweedie distribution using the glmmTMB package in R. I got several fit indices, specifically: AIC, BIC, Logliklihood.

What is the most appropriate way to report on the model's goodness of fit in such a model? Is there a way to extract an interpretable fit measure such as R^2 from these results?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

to those interested, it seems that it is appropriate to compute a "mcfadden pseudo r^2", which is basically 1- (log likelihood model / log likelihood null model).
The null model could be a model with only the intercept. I calculated also a pseudo R2 which compares the full model to a model with random effects, to understand what is the part explained by the fixed effects.
cheers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).